# Convert str() to list() or tuple() without losing quotes

Tags: python, string, list

Good afternoon!
I ran into a problem that on a "pure" python I can't correctly convert a string of the form:

`'("dbfd8379-f50c-4555-bc04-c138413cd27a", "2022-10-06 15:44:46.713", 1, "String for test1")'`

To the list or tuple of the form:

`["dbfd8379-f50c-4555-bc04-c138413cd27a", "2022-10-06 15:44:46.713", 1, "String for test1"]`

`("dbfd8379-f50c-4555-bc04-c138413cd27a", "2022-10-06 15:44:46.713", 1, "String for test1")`

I've tried a lot of options, mostly with replace, strip and split. But all of them did not give the desired result.
I really ask for your help. Please help me to figure it out.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: Why are you storing the tuple? If you need to serialize a data structure consider using pickle https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python-pickling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with `ast.literal_eval()`?

```
text = '("dbfd8379-f50c-4555-bc04-c138413cd27a", "2022-10-06 15:44:46.713", 1, "String for test1")'

import ast
ast.literal_eval(text)
```

Output:

```
('dbfd8379-f50c-4555-bc04-c138413cd27a',
 '2022-10-06 15:44:46.713',
 1,
 'String for test1')
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the terrible question. I concentrated too much on the list() and just missed some details on tuple().
Please tell, is the list() harder to do?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: `list(ast.literal_eval(text))`

Comment: I got too carried away with complex solutions, losing sight of a very simple one. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

1. import ast library
2. use ast.literal_eval("your_string")
   hope u find this usefull.